# Build success but application error in Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, mysql-connector

i'm trying to deploy my python app on heroku with the help of flask. I checked on the local machine it worked fine. When i deploy to the heroku build was success but when i open app it says `application error`
when I log the error with `heroku logs --tail --app` below is the error code.

```
2020-06-02T07:06:41.820850+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
2020-06-02T07:06:41.820850+00:00 app[web.1]: import _version
2020-06-02T07:06:41.820858+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_version'
```

my **requirements.txt**

```
mysql-connector==2.2.9
mysql-connector-python==8.0.20
mysql_connector_repackaged==0.3.1
mysqlclient==1.4.6
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `mysql-connector` is virtual package you don't need to specify in your `requirements.txt` instead of that put `mysql.connector` in your `requirements.txt`
and post if it throws any errors

P.S you don't need to specify any version for `mysql.connector`

HAPPY_CODING

Answer (score 2):

https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector/

Support goes until Python 3.3. It also says in the description:

> Deprecated, go for official version
>   https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python.

Remove the `mysql-connector` dependency.

Comment: i tried without `mysql-connector` and still not working

Comment: You probably have a different error. Which means you need to open a new question since your original question was answered.